# How to start glassfish domain from different path using command line

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish, asadmin

I'm trying to start my local domain from a command line, for some reason my domain was created in a different location so I tried the following command to start the domain:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\glassfish4\glassfish\bin>asadmin start-domain
>   C:\Users\Abraham\personal_domain

but it doesn't work, I got the following error:

There is no such domain directory:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\C:\Users\Abraham\personal_domain
>   Command start-domain failed.

Do I have to add another attribute in the command?, What am I missing?

From NetBeans, it runs fine and I can access to my application but I want to be able to start it from command line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, to find more information about any `asadmin` subcommand, you can use `help` to find the man page for that command in one of two ways:

Either:

```
asadmin help start-domain
```

or

```
asadmin start-domain --help
```

Secondly, to start a domain from a different location, you need to first specify the ***domains directory*** - a folder where the actual domain folder sits, and then the ***domain name***. This will look a lot like you've just typed out the full path to the domain directory, but do be aware that there is a space in between the end of the path and the name of the domain.

e.g. if I wanted to start a domain called "`myDomain`" in a folder `C:\Users\me\domains`, I could do this:

```
asadmin start-domain --domaindir C:\Users\me\domains myDomain
```

*Note the space in between `domains` and `myDomain`.*

So, in your case, you would need to use:

```
asadmin start-domain --domaindir C:\Users\Abraham personal_domain
```

Answer (score 0):

First I would make sure that the domain *personal_domain* is known by the glassfish server. The following statement lists all the known domains.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\glassfish4\glassfish\bin>asadmin list-domains
```

If the `asadmin list-domains` list *personal-domain*, I would try to start the domain using the **domain name** instead of the **domain path** and the `--domaindir` option.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\glassfish4\glassfish\bin>asadmin start-domain personal_domain --domaindir C:\Users\me\domains
```

Comment: This will assume that the domain is still in the default domain directory. Both the path and name need to specified if the domain is not located in `glassfish4\glassfish\domains`